# Determine relationship type using inspection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to determine whether a relationship type is one-to-one retrospectively.

In my use case, a 3rd party developer is able to add new tables (eg Manager and/or Worker) with a one-to-one relationship back to a master table (here called Person). They might also add new tables that are one-to-many; I need to ignore those.

The following snippet:

```py
from sqlalchemy import * 
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
e.execute(""" 
     create table person (id integer primary key) 
""") 
e.execute(""" 
     create table manager (id integer primary key, person_id integer,
     FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES person(id)) 
""") 
e.execute(""" 
     create table worker (id integer primary key, person_id integer,
     FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES person(id)) 
""") 

Base = automap_base() 

class Person(Base): 
    __tablename__ = 'person' 
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 

class Manager(Base): 
    __tablename__ = 'manager' 
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
    person = relationship("Person", uselist=False)

class Worker(Base): 
    __tablename__ = 'worker' 
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
    person = relationship("Person", uselist=False)

class WorkerUnion(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'worker_union' 
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
    person = relationship("Person", uselist=True)    

Base.prepare(e) 

for r in inspect(Person).relationships:
    print(f"{r.target.name}, {r.uselist}, {r.collection_class}")
```

outputs:

```
manager, True, <class 'list'>
worker, True, <class 'list'>
worker_union, True, <class 'list'>
```

Which I find confusing as I specified uselist=False for the manager/worker relationships.

I'm clearly missing something, is there a way to determine the nature of relationship for each class using inspect?

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code to determine a relationship type. I also added the way in which I determine whether it is a Many-to-many or Many-to-one relationship, because I often have to execute based on that condition. Using the example of Person:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces import MANYTOMANY, MANYTOONE
from sqlalchemy import inspect

for relationship in inspect(Person).relationships:
  direction = relationship.direction
  print(direction)

  if direction == MANYTOMANY:
    # execute some code
  elif direction == MANYTOONE:
    # execute some other code
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the helpful suggested answers and comments.

It seems the trick is within each relationship to look at each discovered entity's relationships. Eg:

```py
for r in inspect(Person).relationships:
    for s in inspect(r.entity.entity).relationships:
        if s.entity.entity == Person:
            print(f"{r.target.name}, {s.uselist}, {s.collection_class}")
```